# Retrieving values of attributes in scala

Tags: scala, spray-json

I am working on scala application where I am writing automation test case using bdd cucumber. I have the following code to fetch data from URL.

```scala
val url = "http://api.hostip.info/get_json.php?ip=12.215.42.19"
val result = scala.io.Source.fromURL(url).mkString
println(result)
```

This gives me the following output:

```
[{"Groups": [], "Id": 1}, {"Groups": [], "Id": 2}, "Groups": [], "Id": 3]
```

I  was trying too get it using spray json as follows:

```scala
result.parseJson.asJsObject().getFields("Id")(0).toString().replace("\"", "")
```

But on running code I am getting following error:

```scala
spray.json.DeserializationException: JSON object expected
```

I want to retrieve Id with value 1. Means the output which I am expecting is 1. How can I do that?

Comment: you have got array. not object. You should 1st choose JsArray, 2th -- 1th element, 3rd -- id from element. You can use pattern matching for log invalid cases, like `result.parseJson match { case JsArray(ar) => <your code>; case other => logger.warn("your error message")`
Also you can create own JsonProtocol for your result, as it desribed in documentation for spray json,

Comment: Hey could you please given a example to get Id value?

Comment: HI it is giving me Vector(List("1"), List("2")). How I can retrieve 1 from this?

Comment: also you can fix your question by adding figure braces to last object in array

Answer (score 0):

When you working with something external, you should handle all possible invalid cases. You can got non-json, empty array, object instead of array, unexpected format of object...
When you tried to solve problem, you can use debug or log for solve it, and handle all possible cases.

The example of solution (it's may be invalid so I don't know valid format of Groups):

```scala
import spray.json._
import DefaultJsonProtocol._

import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}

case class GroupsInfo(id: Int, groups: List[Int])

object Stack extends App {
  val jsonAsString = "[{\"Groups\": [], \"Id\": 1}, {\"Groups\": [], \"Id\": 2}, {\"Groups\": [], \"Id\": 3}]"
  implicit val fooFormat: JsonFormat[GroupsInfo] = jsonFormat(GroupsInfo, "Id", "Groups")
  val groupsInfos: Try[List[GroupsInfo]] = Try(jsonAsString.parseJson.convertTo[List[GroupsInfo]])
  groupsInfos match {
    case Success(value) =>
      value.headOption.map(_.id) match {
        case Some(id) => println(s"id=$id")
        case None => System.err.println("result list is empty")
      }
    case Failure(exception) =>
      System.err.println("Invalid format of result")
      exception.printStackTrace(System.err)
  }
}
```

also you can use something like this at your own risk (you can handle somethonk):

```scala
  val jsonAsString = "[{\"Groups\": [], \"Id\": 1}, {\"Groups\": [], \"Id\": 2}, {\"Groups\": [], \"Id\": 3}]"
  val firstId: Int = jsonAsString.parseJson match {
    case JsArray(ar) => ar.head.asJsObject.fields("Id").convertTo[Int]
  }
```

Comment: I don't need to check form validity. I just need value of Id 1 that's it

Comment: It is working fine but want to know How come it is printing id as 1 even there is no check of identifying value of id in your code?

Comment: You means, that Id field may be missed filed in JSON? Or you mean that I don't check type of Id? If you want to filter by Id, you can write `ar.map(_.asJsObject.fields("Id").convertTo[Int]).find(_ == 1).get`

Comment: not sure by looking at your code code it seems it will always take value of Id from first {} . Correct me if I am wrong. If this is the case then there is a possibility I may get id 1 at second {} or third {} and in that case this code will not work fine

Comment: `ar.head` take first element from JSON array

Comment: hey could you please update your code and add a return to  it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218138/discussion-between-mikhail-ionkin-and-admin).